# How to proove $\lim_{x \to a}[f(x)g(x)] = 0$ if $\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-writing

I am working with "Calculus with Analytic Geometry" from the author Leithold and I came to the execrcise where I have to proove that

$\lim_{x \to a}[f(x)g(x)] = 0$

for

$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L\ $ and $\ \lim_{x \to a}g(x) = 0$

The book gives some hints from the beginning of the proof to the end, but I have not been able to put things together.

First it tells me to show that

if $\ 0 < |x - a| < \delta_{1}$, then $|f(x)| < 1 + |L|$, where $\epsilon = 1$.

Then it tells me to show that

if $\ 0 < |x - a| < \delta_{2}$, then $|g(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{1 + |L|}$.

And for the last, it tells me to pick the smallest from $\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ and then theorem is proven.

I could comprehend the if statement for $f(x)$ but not for $g(x)$. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The fact that $\delta_1$ exists making $0 < |x-a| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x)| < 1+|L|$ comes pretty easily from the definition of limit, if you consider the cases $L \geq 0$ and $L < 0$ separately.

Comment: The claim about $|g(x)|$ should not say $\epsilon=1$. It needs to be true for any possible  positive $\epsilon$.

Comment: @aschepler, that's correct. Thanks for pointing that!

Comment: @aschepler, but I still don't get how to apply $1+|L| $ to the $g(x)$ statement

Comment: Oh, I read your last sentence wrong! It would probably help here to keep the variables $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ and overall $\epsilon$ separate like the $\delta$ variables sort of already are. Then it would read like $\epsilon_1 = 1$ and $\epsilon_2 = \epsilon / (1+|L|)$ and $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$.

Comment: Okay, but why I have $\frac{\epsilon}{(1+|L|)}$ in the $g(x)$ statement? It seems weird to have the limit from $f(x)$ with the other statement.

Comment: This is just continuity of multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L\ $ by definition this means that $\forall 
\epsilon \gt 0 \  \exists \delta_1 \gt 0 \ $ such that $\forall x$ if $|x-a| \lt \delta_1$ then $|f(x) - L| \lt \epsilon$.

Now, taking $\epsilon = 1$ we can rewrite $|f(x) - L| \lt 1$, using the rules of absolute value we can say that $$-1 \lt f(x) - L \lt 1$$ $$-1 +L \lt f(x) \lt 1+L,$$ but $-1-L \leq -1+L$ so we can write $$-1 -L \lt f(x) \lt 1+L,$$ and then finally by using the same rule of absolute value $$|f(x)| \lt |1 + L|$$ now using the triangular inequality for absolute value we get $|1 + L| \leq 1 + |L|$ and thus we finally get the result: $$|f(x)| \lt 1 + |L|$$

Second, $\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = 0$ by definition this means that $\forall 
\epsilon \gt 0 \  \exists \delta_2 \gt 0 \ $ such that $\forall x$ if $|x-a| \lt \delta_2$ then $|g(x) - 0| \lt \epsilon$. Notice that the definition states $\forall \epsilon$ so in particular it is true for $\frac{\epsilon}{1+|L|}$ hence we get the result $$|g(x)| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{1+|L|}$$

Lastly to prove the result $\lim_{x \to a}[f(x)g(x)] = 0$, we will use the 2 previous results, however to be able to utilize them the necessary contidions must be met, i.e. $|x-a| \lt \delta_1$ and $|x-a| \lt \delta_2$ for both of these statements to be true we just to let $\delta = min \{ \delta_1, \delta_2 \} $ (which means $\delta$ will be the smallest out of the two).

Now given $\epsilon \gt 0$, let $\delta$ as described above, $\forall x$ such that $|x-a| \lt \delta$ then

\begin{aligned}
|f(x)g(x)| &\leq |f(x)| \cdot |g(x)| \\
&\lt (1+|L|) \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{1+|L|} \\
&= \epsilon
\end{aligned}

Thus we got that $\forall x$ such that $|x-a| \lt \delta$ then $|f(x)g(x)| \lt \epsilon$, thus, by definition of limits, and since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, $\lim_{x \to a}[f(x)g(x)] = 0$